# Mapping function with multiple variables and ingrained list

Tags: list-manipulation

Been working on this for hours, but I can't seem to find something which mimics this.

So I've got parameter values in a list of the form:

```
parameters=
{{{-2, 0.5}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 3}, {-2, 4}}, 
{{-1, 0.5}, {-1,  1}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 3}, {-1, 4}}, 
{{0, 0.5}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0,3}, {0, 4}},
{{1, 0.5}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}},
{{2,0.5}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}}
```

I've got a `MapThread` function:

```
MapThread[f, parameters, 1]
```

which gives

```
{f[{-2, 0.5}, {-1, 0.5}, {0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}, {2, 0.5}], 
f[{-2, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}], 
f[{-2, 2}, {-1, 2}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}], 
f[{-2, 3}, {-1, 3}, {0, 3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}], 
f[{-2, 4}, {-1, 4}, {0, 4}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}]}
```

When I actually want it to give:

```
{{f[-2, 0.5], f[-1, 0.5], f[0, 0.5], f[1, 0.5], f[2, 0.5] }, 
{f[-2, 1], f[-1, 1], f[0, 1], f[1, 1], f[2, 1]}, 
{f[[-2, 2], f[-1, 2], f[0, 2], f[1, 2], f[2, 2]}, 
{f[-2, 3], f[-1, 3], f[0, 3], f[1, 3], f[2, 3]}, 
{f[-2, 4], f[-1, 4], f[0, 4], f[1, 4], f[2, 4]}}
```

Not quite sure what is going wrong.

I am especially interested in how to work with the curly brackets. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MapThread[f @@@ {##} &, parameters]
```

> {{f[-2, 0.5], f[-1, 0.5], f[0, 0.5], f[1, 0.5], f[2, 0.5]},
>      {f[-2, 1], f[-1, 1], f[0, 1], f[1, 1], f[2, 1]},
>      {f[-2, 2], f[-1, 2], f[0, 2], f[1, 2], f[2, 2]},
>      {f[-2, 3], f[-1, 3], f[0, 3], f[1, 3], f[2, 3]},
>      {f[-2, 4], f[-1, 4], f[0, 4], f[1, 4], f[2, 4]}}

you get the same result using

```
f @@@ # & /@ Transpose[parameters]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `Apply[]` at an appropriate level before doing a `Transpose[]`, so you don't need to `Map[]`:

```
Transpose[Apply[f, {{{-2, 0.5}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 3}, {-2, 4}},
                    {{-1, 0.5}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 3}, {-1, 4}},
                    {{0, 0.5}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}},
                    {{1, 0.5}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}},
                    {{2, 0.5}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}}, {2}]]
   {{f[-2, 0.5], f[-1, 0.5], f[0, 0.5], f[1, 0.5], f[2, 0.5]},
    {f[-2, 1], f[-1, 1], f[0, 1], f[1, 1], f[2, 1]},
    {f[-2, 2], f[-1, 2], f[0, 2], f[1, 2], f[2, 2]},
    {f[-2, 3], f[-1, 3], f[0, 3], f[1, 3], f[2, 3]},
    {f[-2, 4], f[-1, 4], f[0, 4], f[1, 4], f[2, 4]}}
```